# Given two unrelated generators $G_1$ and $G_2$, and a third with $H = G_1 + G_2$. Is it hard to compute $xG_1$ from $xH$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory, hardness-assumptions

Given some group in which both discrete logarithms and the computational Diffie-Hellman problem are hard. Furthermore, two random, unrelated group generators $G_1, G_2$, and a third generator defined by $H = G_1 + G_2$. Can you compute $xG_1$ if you know only $G_1$, $G_2$, and $xH$?

**My guess**: I would assume it's hard, because otherwise it would be easy to compute $xG$ knowing only $xH$ for any two unrelated generators $G$ and $H$.

Comment: Hint: try to reduce the computational Diffie-Hellman assumption to this problem.

Comment: `if you know only xH, G_1, and G_1?` - is this a typo, you have mentioned $G_1$ twice?

Comment: @IstvánAndrásSeres I don't think that we know that discrete logarithm being hard implies computational Diffie-Hellman being hard.

Comment: @user93353 you're right! edited it.

Comment: You're right @DanielS! Can we assume the CDH assumption in your applied group, @RobinLinus?

Comment: @IstvánAndrásSeres yes. I'll add it to the question

Comment: Superb! I think now you can prove that your problem is as hard as CDH. Imagine that you have an oracle that solves your problem, and now try to build a machine that solves arbitrary CDH instances with the same success probability as the oracle solving your problem. Hope this helps. If not, let me know and I can write down the proof for you as an answer but I'll leave the joy of thinking for you as of now.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computing $xG_1$ knowing only $G_1$, $G_2$, and $xH$ is as hard as the computational Diffie-Hellman problem (CDH).

For some given $xH$ we can choose, for example, $G_1 = yH$ and $G_2 = H - G_1$. This choice satisfies $H = G_1 + G_2$.

Computing $xG_1$ from $xH$ is equivalent to computing $xyH$, which breaks the CDH assumption.